# sql server 2008 partitioning

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have a basic partitioning question.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherStationData](
    [Time] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [pk_WS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TemperatureF] [decimal](5, 1) NULL,
            ....
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WeatherStationData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Time] ASC,
    [pk_WS] ASC
) [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have created this partition function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfWSD (DATETIME) AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR
VALUES (
    '01/01/2007', 
    '01/01/2008',
    '01/01/2009',
    '01/01/2010',
    '01/01/2011',
    '01/01/2012'
    );
```

And this partition scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psWSD] AS PARTITION [pfWSD] TO (
    [WSD0000]
    ,[WSD2007]
    ,[WSD2008]
    ,[WSD2009]
    ,[WSD2010]
    ,[WSD2011]
    ,[WSD2012]
    )
```

When i run:

```
SELECT $PARTITION.pfWSD([Time]) AS Partition, 
COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] FROM dbo.WeatherStationData
GROUP BY $PARTITION.pfWSD([Time])
ORDER BY Partition ;
```

The results look like this:

```
Partition   COUNT
----------- -----------
2           3396337
3           5408747
4           6576450
5           9602069
6           12650615
7           5577064
```

Yet, when I look at the underlying files, they are all 99% free (initial size was 2048MB, 2047MB free), and the primary file group is still large and mostly full.  The table was empty and I loaded data into it after setting up the partitioning.  I don't think the partitioning worked, what else do I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to create the table on the partition scheme, should be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherStationData](
    [Time] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [pk_WS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TemperatureF] [decimal](5, 1) NULL,
        ....
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WeatherStationData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Time] ASC,
    [pk_WS] ASC
) **psWSD([Time])**
) ON **psWSD([Time])**
```